# Как отправить сообщение в группу через бота?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram, phpstorm

Написал бота, который при нажатии на кнопку должен присылать сообщение в открытую группу, а так же сам код для отправки (важно: нужно именно прислать новое сообщение, а не переслать из чата с ботом существующее)

```
if ($answers[$callback_data]) {
    $answer = $answers[$callback_data];
    $post = [
        'chat_id' => $user_id,
        'message_id' => $message_id,
        'text' => $answer["answer_text"],
        'parse_mode' => 'html',
    ];
if ($answer["support_available"]) {
            $buttons = array_merge($buttons, [['text' => 'Начать диалог', 'callback_data' => 'contact_' . $callback_data]]);
        }

} else {
    $explode_data = explode('_', $callback_data, 2);
    $prefix = $explode_data[0];

    } if ($prefix === 'contact') { // прислать сообщение в группу
        // $send_answers = $explode_data[1];
        $post = [
            'chat_id' => GROUP_ID,
            'text' => 'aaa'
        ];
        telegram('sendMessage', $post);
```

}

Бот в группе является администратором, но сообщения все равно не присылаются при нажатии на кнопку с префиксом contact, возможно что-то упустил важное, но пока не могу найти что именно

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался с решением, оказывается `GROUP_ID` был неправильно указан, он должен начинаться на -100, это можно проверить, отправив запрос по ссылке - [https://api.telegram.org/bot[ТОКЕН_БОТА]/sendMessage?chat_id=@[USERNAME_КАНАЛА]&text=[ЛЮБОЙ_ТЕКСТ]](https://api.telegram.org/bot%5B%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%9A%D0%95%D0%9D_%D0%91%D0%9E%D0%A2%D0%90%5D/sendMessage?chat_id=@%5BUSERNAME_%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%9B%D0%90%5D&text=%5B%D0%9B%D0%AE%D0%91%D0%9E%D0%99_%D0%A2%D0%95%D0%9A%D0%A1%D0%A2%5D)